# Python Improperly Formatting AdSense code for GAE app?`

Tags: python, google-app-engine, adsense

I have an AdSense ad embedding into the page http://mostpopnews.appspot.com/ (on the right most column / blank space) that's generated (along with the rest of the html by Python code used in GAE. It's been about 4 days since I created and embedded the ad script into the site, but the ad status has not changed from "New" to "Active". I am not sure why this is the case, as I have other blogs which convert to Active very quickly. Possibly because the site has not been indexed yet? My main hypothesis is that the Python code used to write the AdSense script is screwing something up with the HTML formatting that I can't see. Any ideas/

Python code for writing adsense script:

```
MAIN_PAGE_HTML = MAIN_PAGE_HTML + '''
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9089661734099673";
/* Top News */
google_ad_slot = "3468761149";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
'''
```

The source code of the webpage shows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9089661734099673";
/* Top News */
google_ad_slot = "3468761149";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the javascript console when your page is viewed ? You have a heap of errors things like  "Blocked a frame with origin "http://mostpopnews.appspot.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: thanks. yeah that's useful, I just don't know how to deal with that error. Googling that error wrt Adsense has people left confused.

Comment: So the error you are getting has nothing to do with the code posted - at least in terms of incorrect formatting etc.. The error you have is all to do with how you are including stuff from adsense.  I don't use adsense so can't make specific comments as to it's use

Comment: you're right, I'm realizing this problem isn't appropriate here.